# Can't focus EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a simple EditText inside my scrollview.
All the other elements are working just fine, however i won't get the usual EditText behaviour on click (Keyboard doesn't appear, I can't write).

Here's my xml for the field.

```
       <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/enterWishprice"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_back"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="0 F€"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

As you can see I already tried setting focusable/inTouchMode.
I also tried setting a click listener on the field to manually open the keyboard which works just fine. However I still can't type anything into the field.
After that i tried using requestFocus in the clicklistener without any result.
Furthermore I tried clearFocus on the EditText as well as the surrounding ScrollView - also not working.

Hopefully you can give me a hint cause I'm out of ideas..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have same problem for my custom edit text. I debug it and setOnFocusChangeListener method of the EditText never called.

Answer (score 1):

The `attribute` Enabled must be set to `true`.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/room_message"
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />
```

But i have got another problem where the `EditText` won't lose focus....

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/enterWishprice"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_back"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:text="0 F€"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="26dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but i still got the same problem. it acts as if there's something on top of it, but why would the click listener work then?

btw: any idea why my question got downvoted? I'm kind of new so I'd like to improve :)